# InvalidOperationException: Stack empty

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

my application was worked fine but suddenly it is stop working and give this error:

```
[InvalidOperationException: Stack empty.]    
System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource) +52
    System.Collections.Generic.Stack`1.Pop() +6694385
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime.WebForms.SelectionMappingRenderTraceListener.EndRendering(TextWriter writer, Object renderedObject) +84    System.Web.UI.RenderTraceListenerList.EndRendering(TextWriter writer, Object renderedObject) +58
    System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +142
    System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +100
    System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25
    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1386
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I had the same problem, but its fixed now. Firstly I disabled PageInspector.

> <appSettings> 
>          <add key="PageInspector:ServerCodeMappingSupport" value="Disabled"/> 
>   </appSettings>

After that I got another error which was related to ResolveUrl method, I removed method and fixed the problem and voila! its working perfectly. Finally, I enabled PageInspector by removing previous settings and still it works.

Comment: Thanks.  This saved my poor head.  It was being banged against a fairly solid wall for the last little while.  Disabling this pointed to the root cause of the problem.

Comment: Thanks as well. I would never have figured this out otherwise.

Comment: How did you know to try disabling PageInspector?

Comment: I found another solution trying to solve a very similar problem. It could be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20406497/system-invalidoperationexception-stack-empty/45888866#45888866

Comment: @Kukoy, I don't remember how as its been a long ago, most probably by using trial and error or reading through msdn reference

Answer (score 1):

For me, it was the **Brower Link**. Disabling it worked for me. For more reference check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/visual-studio/overview/2013/using-browser-link
[image]